# XSS payload without using < and >

Tags: web-application, xss

I am performing testing on a site that takes input from the user and places it between `<span>` and  `</span>`. However, `<` and `>` from the user are encoded as `&lt` and `&gt`. Is there any payload that could possibly execute XSS in the site that doesnot use `<` and `>`?

Comment: Have you tried URL Encoding? %3C and %3E

Comment: %3C and %3E remain as it is. They are not decoded by browser.

Comment: What about through a proxy? (i.e. Burp)

Comment: Sorry I did not get you. Can you explain what do I need to do in Burp suite ?

Comment: Use the Intercept module to intercept the request and inject your XSS payload via the proxy to bypass any client side controls. If you need more help, open a chat for this question and we can talk more.

Comment: The < was intercepted as %3C in the burp, i replaced %3C with <. However, < was still encoded as &lt in response by the server. Sorry i cannot open chat as i lack 20 reputation.

Comment: Then it looks like the filtering is server-side. Try an active scan with burp and keep at it. Good luck

Comment: There are a number of questions here asking the same thing. Please check out the "related questions" panel along the right side.

Comment: simple answer: no, in-tag content without `< or >` _must_ be safe.

Answer (score 7):

Text entities in HTML can't do anything interesting, and the content between span tags is interpreted as text. To do anything interesting, you'll need to inject a new entity (which is done using `<` and `>`), or you'll need your input to be injected into a non-text location (such as the parameters of an entity, or inside a `<script>` block, or similar). If your input isn't being reflected anywhere else, and `<` and `>` are always encoded, then you can't exploit the page via XSS.

However, there might be ways to trick the server into sending un-encoded `<` and `>` without it meaning to. One way that I've seen is to send Unicode characters that aren't `<>` but that the server might map down to those ASCII characters before reflecting them into the output. Consider characters like `˂˃`, `‹›`, `≤≥`, `＜＞`, all of which may get mapped to `<>` by a server and then not get encoded as `&lt; &gt;`. No guarantees, but it does happen.

Comment: fwiw, i've never heard of any server or client auto-converting unicode to `<` or `>`...

Comment: @dandavis You bet there is! For instance, this could happen with punycode conversions.

Comment: @dandavis: I've pentested a lot of web apps. It's not common, but I've seen it happen before. It's another tool for the toolbox, not a guarantee, but it's always worth checking for.

Comment: to clarify: sure, there may be bad code out there that outputs real angle brackets from other "stuff", but i've not encountered such in 10 years of webdev, and as such i believe it to be uncommon and obviously defective, but would be surprised if OP faces such an issue...