# Is XSS possible when the user input gets reflected inside <textarea> when '<' and '>' symbols are sanitized

Tags: web-application, xss, appsec

### The scenario:

I have an application which takes user input and reflect everything to the following field in response.

---

`<textarea rows="5" cols="32" name="test_name" tabindex="6">`**user input** `</textarea>`

---

1. All the user input except *less than (**<**)* and *greater than (**>**)* special characters are reflected.
2. **<** & **>** are sanitized in response by html encoding them (**&lt**, **&gt**).

### Theory, History and the whole story:

In theory to demonstrate XSS, I have to get an alert window. I am listing down the ideal test cases I have tried out. I would like to know if I missed something here.

1. Branch 1: Try to encode < & >
         Tried - URL encoding Result - Failed
2. Branch 2: Try to find alternate ways
         I know that I could have gotten a script executed if my script landed inside a tag like  by using onmouseover, onclick etc.

### The Question:

1. Would XSS be possible in this scenario?
2. What other encoding can I try? [ suggest me payloads ]
3. Is there any other way, like onmouseover & onclick which will work outside the < & > tags?

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times before, eg here: [XSS payload without using < and >](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/130284/xss-payload-without-using-and).

Comment: @tim is right. To keep this question open you'd have argue why this is any different from an ordinary XSS attempt outside of any tags.